# How to create a SET-like type on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to create a column of week days such that we can select more then only one day.

I know the enum type can do that, but it can only contain one item.

How can I create a datatype in PostgreSQL such that I can have something that fuctions like a multiple-choice enum, just like a set on MySQL?

Answer (score 17):

Use the `HSTORE` column type. `HSTORE` stores key/value pairs. You can use null values if you only care about checking if a key exists.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html.

For example, to ask *Is 'x' in my hstore?*, do

```
CREATE EXTENSION HSTORE;  --create extension only has to be done once
SELECT * FROM 'x=>null,y=>null,z=>null'::HSTORE ? 'x';
```

I believe this is operation is *O(1)*. In contrast, checking for containment in an `ARRAY`-type column, is *O(n)*.

Comment: `hstore`'s underlying storage is actually just an array of k/v pairs unfortunately. I'm my tests `?|` on `hstore` is 2-4 times slower than using an array with the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 14):

I guess an array is the closest match to the dreaded set data type.

But that solution is not normalized, and you will probably run into several issues because of that. I'd recommend to store that in a properly normalized table, especially if you plan to query on the selected values or do other reporting on that.

Comment: There are instances where this doesn't work, for example if the primary key of a relation is a set. While the members of the set can be expressed as a joined table, there's no way to guarantee uniqueness or perform fast lookups on set equality (rather than just membership)

Answer (score 12):

[Bit Strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-bitstring.html) `BIT(n)` are the closest PostgreSQL has to MySQL's `SET` types.

For days of the week, use `BIT(7)`.

Unlike MySQL's `SET`, the width of a `BIT` type is not constrained to 64 bits or less.